# "Unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common" in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm compiling a legacy Visual Studio 6.0 C++ application in Visual Studio 2015 and I've run into this error and searching the net hasn't yielded any useful information.

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common referenced in function __except_handler4 (MSVCRT.lib)

I understand that somewhere in the code is referencing a method no longer(?) present in current versions of MSVCRT. Is there a workaround / compiler flag for this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The error message is actually saying the the function `__except_handler4`, defined in MSVCRT.LIB, references the undefined symbol `__except_handler4_common`. So it's not your code that's making the this reference, it's Visual Studio 2015's code.

The symbol `__except_handler4_common` is defined in vcruntime.lib.  This file should be automatically be linked in. I'm not sure why it wasn't. Did you select the static runtime library in the project options ("Multi-threaded (/MT)"), but then manually add MSVCRT.LIB (part of the dynamic C runtime libary)?

Comment: Thanks, Ross. Much appreciated. The vcruntime.lib directory is included in my library paths (they were added/imported during the VC++ 6.0 to Visual Studio 2015 project conversion) but the errors make it look (to me) that it's not being linked in for some reason.  If I add vcruntime.lib to "Additional Dependencies" the error disappears, but  I don't fully understand why that would be the case.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I had a similar error I believe. We have an old C++ executable that gets generated and used in our application. When I tried to build in release mode, I would get 80 build errors, similar to the errors described above. I ended up checking the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies page in my project properties. For some reason someone had added msvcrt.lib to the "Ignore Specific Default Libraries" property. I have no idea why, but I removed that and voila, it built in release without issue.

Comment: In my case, I had a working program that used the static runtime, but then I added a static library that was set to use the runtime as a DLL. Fixing them to both use the same runtime solved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

In your library project, check Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library

Chances are it's set to "Multi Threaded Debug DLL" (/MDd).

If that's the case then try changing it to "Multi Threaded Debug" (/MTd) and rebuild (that worked for me).

Comment: The reason for the error depends, so its best you said this was what worked for me.

Comment: @Dexter's that better?

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this error depends.

For me it was "libcmt.lib" and "libcmtd.lib" listed explicitly among linker inputs, rather than by selecting it from "Runtime Library" field in GUI.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I was linking to the objects of a static project from a non-static unit test. I tried setting the unit test to static build, but then the compiler (VC++ 2015) got the error `An internal error has occurred in the compiler`. I ended up setting both the main project and the unit test project to "Use MFC in a Shared DLL", and then it worked.